# performance benefits of using js prototype for structuring large js application

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

What is the benefit of this:

```
HB.somepackage = HB.somepackage || {};

HB.somepackage.SomeGoodClass = function(someSelector){
    this.someSelector = someSelector;
}

HB.somepackage.SomeGoodClass.prototype.doSomeStuff = function(){
    var $obj = $(this.someSelector);
    // work your magic with $obj;
};
```

as opposed to this:

```
HB.somepackage = HB.somepackage || {};

HB.somepackage.someSelector = "HardCodedValueHere"; 
HB.somepackage.someOtherSelector = "AnotherHardCodedValueHere";

HB.somepackage.SomeReallyBadClass = function(){};

HB.somepackage.SomeReallyBadClass.prototype.doSomeStuff = function(){};
```

Comment: Methods of the prototype are only accessible when the object is created, that is without hitting up the prototype directly. Either through the `new` keyword or using things like `Object.create`. However which you use changes how you create the object. If you existing `HB.somepackage` wasn't created then you won't have access to `doSomeStuff` anyway. EDIT: This was in reply to a previous comment that was since deleted.

Answer (score 1):

There's sort of a lot to consider in this question. But to cover the basics, it comes down to [prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) and lookup.

Your first example:

```
HB.somepackage = HB.somepackage || {};

HB.somepackage.SomeGoodClass = function(someSelector){
    this.someSelector = someSelector;
}

HB.somepackage.SomeGoodClass.prototype.doSomeStuff = function(){
    var $obj = $(this.someSelector);
    // work your magic with $obj;
};
```

This makes `someSelector` a property of `SomeGoodClass` which can change depending on the callee. If I was to create/call that function binded to a different context, `this.someSelector` would correspond to that callee context:

```
var newObject = {someSelector : 'oldSelector'};
HB.somepackage.SomeGoodClass.apply(newObject, 'newSelector');
newObject.someSelector; // 'newSelector'
HB.somepackage.SomeGoodClass.someSelector; // undefined
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeENXj

So here, you may have thought that inside of the `SomeGoodClass` this.someSelector would have referred to `SomeGoodClass.someSelector` but it doesn't.

In your second example:

```
HB.somepackage = HB.somepackage || {};

HB.somepackage.someSelector = "HardCodedValueHere"; 
HB.somepackage.someOtherSelector = "AnotherHardCodedValueHere";

HB.somepackage.SomeReallyBadClass = function(){};

HB.somepackage.SomeReallyBadClass.prototype.doSomeStuff = function(){};
```

`someSelector` is more or less being used as a type of constant that would need to be referenced inside of other functions of `somepackage`

Depending on the context of your application and your desired/preferred coding practices one may be desired over the other. In the second example, calling `apply()` or `call()` on the `SomeGoodClass` function would obviously not change the "internal" `someSelector` attribute of the class but you also wouldn't be able to lookup to the attribute from within the function/object.